# Change alpha-numeric string to unique id

Tags: python, r, bash

I need to convert my three text files to the exact formatting of the corresponding example files in order to run my code. I think the formatting error being generated is from the geneID, consisting of letters and numbers in my files but being only numbers in the example files. The IDs from file1 match the IDs from file2. How would I change the IDs in both files to be unique numbers that still match up between files?

This is the formatting (tab delimited):

---

My file1:

```
AL590447    EcGBM1  mRNA    57215   58105   .   -   .   ECU07_0430-t26_1

AL590451    EcGBM1  mRNA    86606   87067   .   +   .   ECU09_0650-t26_1

AL590449    EcGBM1  mRNA    50646   52472   .   -   .   ECU10_0450-t26_1
```

Example file1:

```
sc14    Cryp_gatt_IND107_V2 mRNA    126181  127026  .   +   .   7000010363306351

sc14    Cryp_gatt_IND107_V2 mRNA    329254  331131  .   -   .   7000010363306425

sc14    Cryp_gatt_IND107_V2 mRNA    553185  557967  .   -   .   7000010363306508
```

My file2:

```
ECU01_0040-t26_1-p1  gene_id=ECU01_0040  locus=AL391737:12389-13003(+)  name=“hypothetical protein” genome=ECU01_0040-t26_1  analysisRun=EcGBM1_FINAL_CALLGENES
MCKDRQHTSRPQIQHNRVKTPLAKLTSTIAKGPLHRRSTMGRHRAAYHRCYRRSSKESSA
IIPCKTRTYSTVSETAWRQTNPSPNELLLSMLPPVPRRPRGGCRPLHAPLLNKMPQTFPA
ASERPMPSRRLSKATQNVQTRPSERPAPCHRRPGPRGPGGRDPPEACHPWSLGPELGLLA
PSEVQFDCLEASRTWNTFIGAYTK*

ECU01_0050-t26_1-p1  gene_id=ECU01_0050  locus=AL391737:13837-14457(+)  name=“hypothetical protein” genome=ECU01_0050-t26_1  analysisRun=EcGBM1_FINAL_CALLGENES
MPRPASHLAPMPSDHPDFRSKSARLRCQPPRTNNCGTFKQPPSVAATSRPKPGNPFLQPP
TKGTPPPKKKKKNHTEGCHTHEANPEPNTKHTETESPKPQTSTQHHTPITIPSSLLSQNT
QREKRGLPLLTSRPSTIPANTYQPQSPHIHSHTPLQRPISTALLHQNLHIRARNIRHTGR
LHGSPTKGAQTAQQAQPHPPKQLATL*
```

Example file2:

```
7000006584189241 gene_id=7000006584189240 locus=CGB_D0230C name="ubiquitin fusion degradation protein UFD1" genome=CNB_WM276_v2 analysisRun=CNB_WM276_v2_Final_CUSTOMCALLGENES_1
MNHGYDSEDEFDSYAAPPPLPGGPASILSHLMGGGFGGFHSAPPPSAYDDYFKAYSTAVM
GGRERPEVMYGGKIIMPPSALARLSALDIPSPWTFQLRNPRSPTQHTTHAGVLEFIAEEG
IVHLPAWMMKRLNLEEGDPVRLTGAKLPKGKMVKIQAQSTDFLQVSDPKSVLESALRFYS
TLSPNDIIEITYNSLTFEFLIMSVVPEGPGISVIDTDLEVDFATPKGYVEPPRPEPKPIP
TMADKLNIDLSSNEPTASGAASVSGGSRPGTSMGTQTPVESFTGVGQSLSGKKVKGKGLA
KKIEEVDSSSKINRADGPRIINTSSLSSANAQVPSALILPEGKFFFGFKYIPYDPSKAPK
PSLADQQKVELQPFGGEGNTLKNGKRVGGGEGKGKEKEKAADEEKEDPWAKLGSGNTLKR
TTATAASSSSNPVPASAPQKEFETRKATEQEIIDATMLDEDDFMFEDEEDDEDDVIEIDS
DYE*

7000006584189251 gene_id=7000006584189250 locus=CGB_E2410W name="hypothetical protein" genome=CNB_WM276_v2 analysisRun=CNB_WM276_v2_Final_CUSTOMCALLGENES_1
MATNPDSRPLPDGWVQQFNSEHQAWFYVNTKAPGGPASQWTHPADDQPTYAPPPGNPPSK
TSTPFAPADDKSRGASEPYYQSSTPQPSGLQQAPYQPASQSASPGPQSQQEKKRGIGGFF
SKLSGNNKPSGYQQGYGQAYPQQQQYGAYPQQQYGYAQQPMYQQQPMYQQQPMYAQRPQR
AGMGAGGAAALGVGGGLLGGMLIGDMISDSQHDAYMDGYQDGDMGDMGGGDFGGDF*
```

Comment: Please post your first try at this; StackOverflow is not a code-writing service, but a place to help you fix your own code.

Comment: This question is better suited to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/